# MySQL - installed version 5.5 but mysql --version says 5.0.95

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, installation

I'm running CentOS 5.2 and upgraded MySQL to 5.5. When I run `mysql` I get this:

```
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 11
Server version: 5.5.45 MySQL Community Server (GPL)
```

But when I run `mysql --version` I get this:

```
mysql  Ver 14.12 Distrib 5.0.95, for redhat-linux-gnu (x86_64) using readline 5.1
```

Since the `mysqld` is `mysql55-mysqld` I'm sure I'm running 5.5, but why am I getting the wrong version with the version command?

Comment: Did you update the client too, or just the server? `mysql` is the client binary.

Comment: I ran `yum install mysql55-server mysql55`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem may happen if you have multi MySQL instances on the same machine. There was pre-installed MySQL when the OS was installed, or using auto installation methods like `yum`: in this case when you type mysql it will point to the pre-installed one since the environment variable point there. you can test it by going to `/mysql/install/path/bin` use `./mysql --version` this should show you the exact version of MySQL.

Comment: I did a `yum erase mysql` first then ran `yum install mysql55`. Is there anything else I can do to remove all vestiges of mysql and run only mysql55?

Comment: to remove MySQL completely form CentOS  you need to run the following commands:

1) `yum remove mysql mysql-server`    2) `mv /var/lib/mysql /var/lib/mysql_old_backup`

Answer (score -3):

1) Reboot Mysql Server (/etc/init.d/mysql restart)
If that fails, shut down machine and reboot

Comment: No need for any reboot, the server shows the right version.